# How to write test case for click event and toHaveBeenCalledWith?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a component returning a button. The button is a onclick link with 2 params. How do I write test case with `toHaveBeenCalledWith`?

```
export const TestCompo = (a, b) => {
  const handleClick = (param_1, param_2) => {
    // * do something
  };

  return (
    <a
      onClick={() => {
        handleClick(a, b);
      }}
    />
  );
};

// how to write test
element.find("a").at(0).simulate("click");
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith();
expect(jest.fn()).toBeCalledTimes(1);
```

Comment: `expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith()` expects a mock function you literally just created and passed to expect to have been called, which it definitely won't have been (nor does it have any connection to the implementation). Test the _behaviour_ - what is the _something_ that's _done_ when the button's clicked, assert on that.

Answer (score 0):

With Enzyme as the question was tagged (which is only supported through React 16) would be written something like this:

```js
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

describe('TestCompo', () => {
  it('test handleClick', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<TestCompo a="paramA" b="paramB"/>);
    wrapper.instance().handleClick= jest.fn();
    wrapper.find("a").at(0).simulate("click");
    expect(wrapper.instance().handleClick).toHaveBeenCalledWith("paramA", "paramB");
  })
})
```

After React 17, React Testing Library` is the [recommended](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/testing.html#tools) React testing library. Note that it is encouraged by the library to reflect the way a user would interact and directly checking a function would be done by checking the *effect* of the function that a user sees. It would be written like this:

```js
import {render, screen} from '@testing-library/react'
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event'

describe('TestCompo', () => {
  it('test handleClick', () => {
    const user = userEvent.setup()
    render(<TestCompo a="paramA" b="paramB"/>);
    await user.click(screen.getByText(linkText));
    expect(somethingThatIsUpdatedOnThePage).toBe(expectedUpdate);
  })
})
```

Comment: I was using mount/shadow, but it said buttClick does not exist.

Comment: It's not a property of the element, it's a nested function. The RTL approach is the correct one whether you're using Enzyme or not.